# What does "hot out" mean in "Why we get cranky when it's hot out"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Ok, I found the sentence

> Why we get cranky when it's hot out

on the internet, but I'm not sure what the word "hot out" mean?

Does it mean "hot out *there*"?

Comment: It means it's hot *outside*, i.e., not indoors.

Comment: It means you can fry an egg on the sidewalk.

Comment: It should be noted that the original phrase, before it was edited by a 3rd party, was all leading caps, suggesting that it was from the title of an article, not normal text.  This is one reason why the phrase is so terse.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** "It's hot out"  uses the impersonal "it" and is similar to "It is raining."

**2.** "out" refers specifically to the temperature in the open, i.e. outside of buildings or covered shaded areas.

**Paraphrases**

*The temperature is very high on the outside of the (shady or air-conditioned) place where I am currently situated.*

or more simply

*The outdoors temperature is very high around here.*

Answer (score 2):

It should have probably been:

> Why we get cranky when it's hot outside.

Comment: Why "should"? *It's hot out* is idiomatic in both British and American English.